# Regex match optional value after dot start

Tags: regex

I have a string in unknown position (**Category**) after 1st one (**EventType**), and I want to match 2nd one if exists.
For ex. i have these inputs:

```
1- ...43239835811840,"EventType":"INFO","SeverityValue":2,"Severity":"INFO","EventID":7036...
2- ...43239835811841,"EventType":"ALERT","SeverityValue":2,"Category":"Logoff","Opcode":"Info"...
3- ...43239835811841,"SeverityValue":2,"Category":"Logoff","Opcode":"Info"...
```

As i need to extract value of **EventType** and **Category** I want to match only with number 1 and 2
I wrote a regex like this:

```
^.*EventType":"(?P<EventType>[^"]+).*("Category":"(?P<Category>\w+))?
```

But it will match **EventType** values not **Category** value on number 2

https://regex101.com/r/si8D3e/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with an alternation in last non-capture group:

```sh
\bEventType":"(?P<EventType>[^"]+).*?(?:"Category":"(?P<Category>\w+)|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/si8D3e/2)

Please take a note of `(?:"Category":"(?P<Category>\w+)|$)` that allows it to match till end if `Category` section is not found.

Comment: What about if there are multiple optional values? like: https://regex101.com/r/Kobcqg/1

Comment: I request you to please avoid modifying requirements now. For this one [you can try this regex](https://regex101.com/r/Kobcqg/2)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
(?:"EventType":"(?P<EventType>.*?)([^"]*))|(?:"Category":"(?P<Category>.*?)([^"]*))
```

[Demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/19ZaoJ/1)

***Explanation:*** This will simply look from `"EventType":"` till `"` with same capturing group name. Similarly it will match `"Category":"`till `"` with Category capturing group name.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing some nuance to your problem, this should work:

```regex
^.*"EventType":"(?P<EventType>.*?)".*"Category":"(?P<Category>.*?)".*$
```

### Demo

This approach basically just looks for the `"EventType"` and `"Category"` keys in a given line of the log file, and then extracts the values in two named capture groups.  Note that the above pattern will not match a line having only one or the other of the keys.

Comment: I think OP wants to get 2 matches

Comment: ...and I don't see the point of doing that, since the extra captured text is trivial given the named capture and knowing how the regex was created.